# getting values from a second window to the main window in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf application which will work minimized. The application will  show a second window when system wakes up from sleep. In the second window there is a combobox and a button. when i click on the button it should set the value of a variable in the mainwindow with the value of combobox. But the problem is the variable in mainwindow is not accessible in second window. How to do this?? I searched a lot in net. But unable to find a working solution. Any suggestions??

Comment: 2 solutions - 1.While creating child window You need to hook some EventHandler inside your Main window to some event of a child form. 2. Read about Observer Design Pattern

Comment: You can use same ViewModel for both windows....

Comment: Try EventAggregator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Comment: I'd create a ViewModel for the data to exchange (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and pass it to both of the Window ViewModels. This makes sharing explicit and you don't have to share the complete ViewModel between both windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Event / delegate approach to get it:

A code snippet to sum-up:

In your First window when creating the second one do

```
Window1 win = new Window1();
win.GetEvent += win_GetEvent;
win.ShowDialog();
```

And in the second window you have:

```
public object ValueToGet;
public delegate object GetValueDelegate(object _value);
public  event GetValueDelegate GetEvent;
public Window1()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      GetEvent.Invoke(ValueToGet);
}
```

Well I don't know which your specific requirment but just to intreduce the approach